# Java annotation that summarizes other annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I would like to create an annotation for a JPA Entity field which summarizes some other annotations. This is the annotation I would like to create:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;

@Target(value = {ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "createdAt", column = @Column(name = "created_at", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "lastChangedAt", column = @Column(name = "last_changed_at", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "lastChangedBy", column = @Column(name = "last_changed_by")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "createdBy", column = @Column(name = "created_by")) })
public @interface EmbeddAdministrativeData {

}
```

But this gives a syntax error at @Embedded because the target of @Embedded is Field and Method. If I remove @Embedded and use it separately the @EmbeddAdministrativeData annotation is ignored. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: I don't think I follow. You've created your own annotation and are asking how to make hibernate recognize it? The answer, I'm afraid, is you can't - not unless you create your own fork of Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.2 supports "meta-annotations" as per [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/annotations.html#meta_annotations). Then it comes down to whether your JPA provider supports JPA 2.2 or not (the one I use, that these docs are for does, for example).

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to do. See my code above. But 
`@Embedded` gives a syntax error because its target is field or method. And if I only use `@AttributeOverrides...` in my meta-annotation it is just ignored at runtime.

Comment: Its target is not just FIELD/METHOD in JPA 2.2, hence why they can be used by a valid JPA 2.2 provider. https://github.com/datanucleus/javax.persistence/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/persistence/Embedded.java#L49